# Is Rosh HaShanah to be observed as if it were a Saturday?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Is Rosh HaShanah to be observed as if it were a Saturday?

Leviticus 23:24-25 implies this.

Does this extend to the second day, or only apply to the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On holidays, all "work" is prohibited other than things related to food preparation and consumption. It's a detailed list, but some examples are:

On Rosh Hashannah, you can grind, cook, bake (using an existing flame) and do anything that's related directly to your meals for that day. Carrying in a public domain is also allowed on Thursday and Friday, this year. These are prohibited on Shabbat.

What I mentioned applies to both days of Rosh Hashanna each year, unless, of course, the first day is on Shabbat. In that case, Shabbat rules have priority.

Comment: consider adding sources.